# Finding the number of solutions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to compare my answer with a friend's and we are both confident in our answers. But the problem is, they are different. So the problem goes:

Suppose I have the equation 
$$x+y+z+w = 14$$
where $x,y,z,w \in \mbox{Z}^+$ (i.e. integers that can be zero or positive) such that $x,y,w,z \le 6$.

**Friend's approach:**

let $X=x+1, Y=y+1, Z=z+1, W=w+1$, so
$$X+Y+Z+W = 10$$

and without the final restriction, applying stars and bars, we get the number of ways :
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
13  \\
3  \end{array} \right)$$
but we need to exclude cases where $1$ of the $4$ has $6$ or more, thus the final answer is:
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
13  \\
3  \end{array} \right)- 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
4  \\
1  \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{cc}
7  \\
3  \end{array} \right)=146$$

**My Way:**

I incorporated the inclusion-exclusion idea

So using: $$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
r+M-1  \\
M-1   \\ \end{array} \right)$$ where M represents different kinds of objects and r is the number of such objects, 
I first found all of the possible nonnegative solutions with no restrictions:
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
14+4-1  \\
4-1   \\ \end{array} \right) =  \left( \begin{array}{cc}
17  \\
3   \\ \end{array} \right)$$

Then I let $x,y,z,w \ge 7$ to be used for the solutions that are not allowed and since there are four variables and their restrictions are all the same, I multiply the following by $C(4,1) = 4$:
$$ 4\left( \begin{array}{cc}
(14-7)+4-1  \\
4-1   \\ \end{array} \right) =  4\left( \begin{array}{cc}
10  \\
3   \\ \end{array} \right)$$

And for the last part, I kept the restriction but now choose two variables of the four. I'll also be multiplying the following by $C(4,2) =6$ since there are six ways of pairing up the variables so:
$$ 6\left( \begin{array}{cc}
(14-7-7)+4-1  \\
4-1   \\ \end{array} \right)=  6\left( \begin{array}{cc}
3  \\
3   \\ \end{array} \right)$$

So by the inclusion-exclusion idea, the number of solutions:

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
17  \\
3   \\ \end{array} \right)- 4\left( \begin{array}{cc}
10  \\
3   \\ \end{array} \right) + 
6\left( \begin{array}{cc}
3  \\
3   \\ \end{array} \right) = 206$$

**Conclusion:**

So which one of us is correct? I've asked this problem before and had a member from this site confirm my answer already so I am set on it. But my friend has two confirmations from math/cs majors. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry about that. It is fixed now.

Comment: I think neither formula is correct , just write them all out and count them (or if you are lazy if you cont more thamn 206 different ways  you are both wrong)

Comment: @Willemien  How many times did you count 3+3+3+5=14? It counts 4 times, from shuffling assignments of $x,y,z,w$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friend has a bug, when plugging in $X,Y,Z,W$ he should have gotten $X+Y+Z+W=18$ to match your expression. I don't know what he was subtracting (oh because he started from a wrong equation!)

Also, your friend's formula given his reduction is also not right. Once you reduce to the case where $X,Y,Z,W$ are strictly positive, the stars and bars approach gives you $18-1$ positions for the dividers and $4-1$ dividers to place.

I think your approach is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is counting the solutions where $ 1 \le w,x,y,z \le 6$; you are counting the solutions where $ 0 \le w,x,y,z \le 6$.

Since the problem statement says $x, y, z, w \in Z^+$, I think your friend has the proper interpretation.

Comment: Yeah, we were thinking the same thing. We are told that the integers can be zero or positive so it makes it weird.

Comment: Ah that makes a little more sense, but then the friend should not have used X,Y,Z,W reduction and reasoned directly.